# How do I show a Drupal 8 contact form on a page?

Tags: entities, emails

I've created a new content type called "Form Page", with a required field being a reference to a contact form. So on the page you would have a body, and under that the contact form itself. I can't seem to figure out how to display the form on the page. I either get a link, or the system name of the contact form printed out. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There needs to be a little more to the Contact Form entity for you to be able to display it.  The easiest way to get this is to install the [Contact Storage](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_storage) module.  After doing this, your manage display options will include "Rendered entity" which will give you the contact form as you hoped and expected!

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out! Just out of curiosity, what would be the recommended way of displaying a contact form on the front-end?

Comment: Oh dear— what i described *is* the recommended way of displaying a contact form on the front end (other than the built-in way of a standalone page of course).  If you want to embed a contact form within a node edit page... this won't do that.  And really, you probably shouldn't.  I'd be curious about the use case for why you'd want to...

Comment: Sorry if this is a noob question, but what's the built-in way of a standalone page?

Comment: @Pim The default contact form is always viewable at /contact but all the contact forms you create can be viewed at /contact/[machine_name], for instance /contact/feedback